# Variables arent changing in the if statemene even though it runs through it

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class LeaderBoardViewController: UIViewController {
    struct Person{
        var placePoints:Int
        var placeNames:String
    }
    var firstPlace = Person(placePoints:2,placeNames:"")
    var secondPlace = Person(placePoints:1,placeNames:"")
    var thirdPlace = Person(placePoints:1,placeNames:"")
    var check = 0
    var uid = ""
    var uniqueNumber:Int?
    var documentdata:[String:Any] = ["":""]
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPlaceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var secondPlaceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var thirdPlaceLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var reloadLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createLeaderboard()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func createLeaderboard(){
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document("0UniqueNumber").getDocument { (document,error) in
            print("wheat the he")
            if error != nil{
                print("cant get data")

            }
            if document != nil && document!.exists{
                print("its here")
                if let documentdata = document?.data() {
                    self.uniqueNumber = documentdata["tally"] as? Int
                    print(self.uniqueNumber)
                    print("FDSFSF")
                    self.rat()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func rat(){
        //var firstPlacePoints:Int?
        //var firstPlaceName:String?
        //var secondPlacePoints:Int?
        //var secondPlaceName:String?
        //var thirdPlacePoints:Int?
        //var thirdPlaceName:String?

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        for index in 0...self.uniqueNumber!-1{
            let indexString = String(index)
            db.collection("leaderboard").document(indexString).getDocument { (document,error) in

                if error != nil{
                    print("cant get data")

                }
                if document != nil && document!.exists{

                    if let documentdata = document?.data() {
                        self.check = documentdata["points"] as! Int
                        self.uid = documentdata["uid"] as! String
                        print("ahwehfesfhsadfsfdsdfsdfsdfsdf")
                        if (self.check > self.firstPlace.placePoints){
                            self.secondPlace.placePoints = self.firstPlace.placePoints
                            self.secondPlace.placeNames = self.firstPlace.placeNames
                            self.firstPlace.placePoints = self.check
                            self.firstPlace.placeNames = self.uid

                            print("hi")
                        }else if(self.check < self.firstPlace.placePoints && self.secondPlace.placePoints < self.check){
                            self.thirdPlace.placePoints = self.secondPlace.placePoints
                            self.thirdPlace.placeNames = self.secondPlace.placeNames
                            self.secondPlace.placePoints = self.check
                            self.secondPlace.placeNames = self.uid

                        }else if(self.check < self.secondPlace.placePoints && self.thirdPlace.placePoints < self.check){
                            self.thirdPlace.placePoints = self.check
                            self.thirdPlace.placeNames = self.uid
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //setGuys()

        }
        print(self.firstPlace.placePoints)
    }
}
```

At the end when I print self.firstPlace.placePoints, it prints the original value when I initialized it. It changes the values in the if statement and I check that with the print statements. However like I said when I run the print statement it doesn't update. Does this have to do something with local variables? Thank you for any help.

Comment: No. It happens because your code is asynchronous, so first you print `self.firstPlace.placePoints` and _then_ you change it. Please read http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: i see so where would I put it so it only runs once?

Comment: where can I put that statement so it would fix itself?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running through a loop and calling an asynchronous method. It's likely that your loop completes before your async method completes. You should wait until the async method completes before you call it again. So something like this might do:

```
func createLeaderboard() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("users").document("0UniqueNumber").getDocument { document, error in
        guard let document = document,
            let documentData = document.data(),
            let tally = documentData["tally"] as? Int,
                document.exists,
                error == nil else {
                    print("Failed")
                    return
            }
        self.rat(index: 0, tally: tally)
    }
}

func rat(index: Int, tally: Int) {
    guard index < tally else {
        return
    }

    let indexString = String(index)
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("leaderboard").document(indexString).getDocument { document, error in
        guard let document = document,
            let documentData = document.data(),
            document.exists,
            error == nil else {
                print("Failed")
                return
        }

        guard let check = documentData["points"] as? Int,
            let uid = documentData["uid"] as? String else {
                print("Missing data")
                return
        }

        // ...
        // Do whatever else you have to do here
        // ...

        // Now you're ready make the next call
        self.rat(index: index + 1, tally: tally)
    }
}
```